# js strange behavior Array Destructuring

Tags: javascript, destructuring

```js
const test = () => {
  const arr = [1, 2]
  console.log("any strings") // focus on this line
  [arr[0], arr[1]] = [arr[1], arr[0]]
}

const test1 = () => {
  const arr = [1, 2]
  console.log("any strings"); // add a semicolon will works or comment this line will works too
  [arr[0], arr[1]] = [arr[1], arr[0]]
}

test() // error

test1() // works
```

Why does the first function test throw error "Cannot set property '2' of undefined"?

Comment: If you want to omit semicolons and [let them be automatically inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/1048572) where ever <s>possible</s> needed, you will [need to put one at the *begin*](https://web.archive.org/web/20201206065632/http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) of every line that starts with `(`, `[`, `/`, `+`, `-` or `\``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here doesn't have anything to do with destructuring. In the first snippet, because the second line after `console.log` begins with an opening bracket, it considers the lines as part of the same statement.

```
console.log("any strings")[arr[0], arr[1]]
```

Note that in bracket notation, `[arr[0], arr[1]]` will resolve to `[arr[1]]` - that's the comma operator. So, it's attempting to assign to the `[arr[1]]` = `[2]` property of the result of calling `console.log("any strings")`. To the interpreter, it's identical to this snippet:

```js
const test = () => {
    const arr = [1,2]
    console.log("any strings")[arr[0], arr[1]]
      = [arr[1], arr[0]]    
} 

test()
```

Same as:

```js
const test = () => {
    const arr = [1,2]
    console.log("any strings")[arr[1]]
      = [arr[1], arr[0]]    
} 

test()
```

Of course, `console.log` returns `undefined`; it has no such property [2]. Always use semicolons when in doubt.